# Laravel 5.3 - changing auth routes for reset password

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

After moving controllers for auth to my `Http/Controllers/Admin/Auth` directory, as well as moving views for auth to `admin/auth` and setting the routes file like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

When clicking the link in reset password email, I get an error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

I have modified showResetForm method in the controller like so:

```
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return view('admin.auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }
```

This are the routes listed on `php artisan route:list`:

```
           POST      | admin/password/email             |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,web,guest |
|        | POST      | admin/password/reset             |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,web,guest |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/password/reset             |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,web,guest |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/password/reset/{token}     |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,web,guest |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/register                   |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,web,guest |
|        | POST      | admin/register                   |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,web,guest
```

The link that a user receives in a mail for password reset is still pointing to the old route without an admin prefix, how can I change that?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to overwrite `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword` class `toMail` function. Replace `[URL_TO_RESETPWD]` with your URL.

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class AppResetPassword extends ResetPassword {

    // Overriding the function
    public function toMail($notifiable) {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', [URL_TO_RESETPWD], $this->token))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
}
```

Next In your admin user model overwrite `sendPasswordResetNotification` function of `CanResetPassword` trait to use your above class.

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token) {
    $this->notify(new App\Notifications\AppResetPassword\ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and wanted to use my own plain text email.

Add to your `User` model:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    Mail::send(['text' => 'emails.password'], ['token' => $token], function ($message) {
        $message->subject(config('app.name').' Password Reset Link');
        $message->to($this->email);
    });
}
```

Create `views/emails/password.blade.php`:

```
You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.

Click here to reset your password: {{ url('auth/password/reset/'.$token) }}

If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.
```

This will send them a plain text password reset email and will get rid of the `password.reset` route not found error.

Comment: For anyone looking to generate the url based on the route name, you could use: route('password.reset', ['token' => {your token}])